# Не подключается скрипт JS на Github Pages

Tags: javascript, html, github

Загрузил свою работу на гитхаб, но на Github Pages видно, что скрипт не подключился.
https://indy660.github.io/raspisanieGonok/ сама страница

https://github.com/Indy660/raspisanieGonok/tree/gh-pages

При этом код функционирует в джсфидл (jsfiddle.net/Indy660/qheaus12/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй переместить скрипты перед

```html
</body>
```

Может быть такое, что сначала у тебя загружается скрипт, но твои id указанные дальше в html разметке он не находит.

Answer (score 1):

Кто найдёт это вопрос, если вы подключали через файл main (и в одном файле объявляли классы и так далее), то подключите script и все ваши js файлы в heade (объявите) и уже перед "/body" указывайте объекты -> (скрины снизу).
После этого у вас будет работать Git Pages.
[image: head и js подключение]
[image: Создание объектов класса в body]

Comment: Текстовую информацию нужно добавлять в виде текста. [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)